# Return entities after intersecting with list of web controls using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I can use the following to return the IDs (strings) that match following an intersect:

```
var ids = db.QuestionOption
            .Select(a => a.ControlID)
            .Intersect(cs.Select(b => b.ClientID))
            .ToList();
```

How would I intersect with the IDs but fetch the entity, not just its matching ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can get the `Ids`:

```
var idList = cs.Select(b => b.ClientID);
```

Then you can use `Contains` like this:

```
var result = db.QuestionOption.Where(a => idList.Contains(a.ControlID)).ToList();
```

Or, you can use `join`:

```
from q in db.QuestionOption
join x in cs on q.ControlId equals x.ControlId
select q
```

Comment: Your first solution suits perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a where clause instead of intersect:

```
var objs = db.QuestionOption.Where(a => cs.Select(b => b.ClientId).ToList().Contains(a.ControlID)).ToList();
```